# Subclassing Control

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

In WINAPI, which is correct/necessary?

```
SetWindowLongPtr(HelpBox, GWLP_USERDATA, static_cast<LONG_PTR>(SetWindowLongPtr(HelpBox, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)(Subclass))));
```

OR

```
SetWindowLongPtr(HelpBox, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)(Subclass));
```

Then in WM_DESTROY I do both like:

```
SetWindowLong(HelpBox, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG) Original);
```

Why should I use the first one over the second? I noticed it had the GWLP_USERDATA and setwindowlongptr twice.. Why? I saw both examples on MSDN and I don't know when to use the first over the second.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **[`SetWindowSubclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** instead; it handles the burden of associating data with the window. anyway. the first one stores the old window proc address in user data storage associated with the window, and you can't do that unless the window class is one you've defined yourself. i.e. <del>where such storage does exist for the window</del> where you are guaranteed that that storage isn't used for anything else.

Comment: uhm, sorry for the edit. i mixed up non-negative index for custom user data storage, with `GWLP_USERDATA` which is a single item storage and always present. but the same caveat applies. one needs full control to use it.

Comment: Can you tell me what the last two parameters of SetWindowSubclass does? Why do I need them? I was writing a class to make windows and I kinda don't want to have to keep track of all ID's if they are needed.
http://pastebin.com/ePbbM57x <-- Like that. Do I have to keep track of a global ID for every subclass? What happens if two ID's are the same?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: the id is used for removing the subclassing (typically you'd do that on receipt of `WM_DESTROY`). since the removal function takes the window handle as argument, as well as the subclass' window procedure address, you can just choose a constant id, such as 0 or 1 :-). the only exception i can think of is when the code is such that subclassing the same window twice or more with the same subclass window procedure, can happen, and then the id at least in principle allows proper order-independent cleanup

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: the last parameter is a data item that is provided to your window procedure. typically you will let that be a pointer to a C++ class type object. then the window procedure can forward to a member function of that object, and that object then provides you with a much more general way to associate data with the window, namely as ordinary C++ data members.